# HTML: why isn't the input field SIZE deprecated? we have style="width:xx"!

Tags: html, input

simply put, i think that the input 'size' field is now obsolete (like the rest of html styling outside of css), and most of the sizing attributes have been deprecated, so why not input.size?

Comment: Voting to close as "not a real question"

Comment: the real question is who are you asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a rhetorical question really... or an attempt at persuasive argument. You are right, though-- it could easily be deprecated and CSS take over. As for why, that answer can only come from someone inside W3C who is part of the decision making process. You could also ask why cellpadding, cellspacing, and width properties are not deprecated in tables.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you got confused between `size` and `width`/`height` attributes (btw I got confused at first when you said field). But assuming you didn't, let me explain what `size` is for.

### `size` attribute

The attribute `size` for element `<input>` applies to text inputs, like e-mail, password, etc. <strike>It defines the maximum character width for the input. Let's say for example you want the maximum password length to be 4 to screw the users, you give it `size=4`, so you cannot enter passwords like *dinosaur* (anything you type after *dino* will not appear unless you delete the previous letters first)</strike>

Edit: *as pointed out by Maksym in the comments, the above is defined by* `maxwidth`, *not* `size`. `size` is, if we refer to [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#adef-size-INPUT),

> except when type attribute has the value "text" or "password". In that case, its value refers to the (integer) number of characters.

So `size=4` is about 4 (monospaced?) characters wide (My experiment with Google Chrome has makes it `size+1` though, i.e. `size=4` is 5 characters wide.)

### Dimension attributes

Now in case of the dimension attributes `width` and `height`. For `<input>` elements, they apply only to image buttons. They define the dimensions of the button. Now why can't you just apply CSS to them?

First, know that CSS is for visual purposes. Image buttons submit coordinates that the user clicked on. This behavior needs to be consistent across browsers, whether they support CSS or not. See this warped image:

[image]

There may be a case where the user is asked to click the letter *e* for the form submit to be processed differently. Probably the server will check whether the x coordinate is `75 <= x <= 90`. But if you defined the dimension with CSS, browsers which disabled CSS will see this image instead:

[image]

And the previous coordinate range check is no longer valid, seeing that the letter *e* is further to the right, hardly within 75 and 90 (and you need to click on the left side of the first `o` to get the same input).

Comment: The size attribute in text input elements determines the visual size of the element in character size not the length of the string you can put into the field. To make your password example true you need to set the maxlength property

Answer (score 2):

The best answer I can give you to your non-question is that HTML isn't a purist language--while it's getting back to it's roots of being *just* content and not style or behavior, it still has it's legacy from the 90's and 00's, which means it still has concerns beyond just content.

Answer (score 0):

There's a valid reason why this attribute isn't deprecated: **"Web Usability"**

When a user views your site, considering the CSS is turned of or unavailable, it's really a bad idea to let the person see a *long field* while in fact, the field only requires a few characters *(such as ids, phone numbers, etc.)*.

CSS is good, yes, but only if you also considered people who won't be able to use them.